# Assebler, exe-шник бездействует, или как сделать вывод на консоль

Tags: masm, ассемблер, masm32

Компилирую ассемблеровский код командами

```
C:\masm32\progs\> ml /c /coff /Cp intsum.asm
```

линкую

```
C:\masm32\progs\> link /subsystem:windows intsum.obj
```

забавно вот только, что когда запускаю exe-шник, абсолютно ничего не происходит, а на команду

```
C:\masm32\progs\> intsum.exe
```

консоль динамит и выдаёт просто

```
C:\masm32\progs\>
```

приводу исходный код (*после неудачи переписал всё подчистую с учебник, добавил больше библиотек, чтобы не ругался на unsolved константы типа _MessageBoxA@6, но, впрочем, не в этом дело*)

```
TITLE Программа суммирования целых чисел (intsum.asm)

.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
;Запрашивает 3 целых числа
;сохряняет их в массиве dword элементов
;сумммирует их и выводит результат
ReadInt PROTO
WriteInt PROto
WriteString PROTO
MassageBoxA PROTO , :DWORD, :DWORD ,:DWORD ,:DWORD
INCLUDE    C:\masm32\include\Irvine32.inc
INCLUDELIB C:\masm32\lib\Kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB C:\masm32\lib\Irvine32.lib
INCLUDELIB C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
.data
    IntCount = 3
    array DWORD IntCount DUP(?)
  promtinptxt BYTE  "Введите целое число со знаком: ", 0
 promtoutptxt BYTE  "Сумма чисел равна ", 0

.code
main PROC
;----------------------------------------------------
;главная процедура, управляет всеми действиями
;вызываются  Clrscr, PromtForInt, ArraySum, DisplaySum
;----------------------------------------------------
     ;   call ClrScr
    mov esi, offset array
    mov ecx, IntCount
    call PromtForInt
    call ArraySum
    call DisplaySum
    exit
main ENDP

;---------------------------------------------------
PromtForInt PROC
;
; Запрашивает у пользователя несколько целых чисел
; и записывает их в массив
; Передаётся: ESI = адрес массива
;         ECX = размер массива
; Возвращается: ничего
; Вызывает: ReadInt, WriteString
;---------------------------------------------------
    pushad
    mov edx, offset promtinptxt
   L1:
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov [esi], eax
    add esi, 4
      ;  call CrLf

   LOOP L1
    popad
ret
PromtForInt ENDP
;---------------------------------------------------
ArraySum PROC
;
; Вычисляет сумму элементов массива dword
; Передаётся: ESI = адрес массива
;         ECX = размер массива
; Возвращается: EAX = сумма массива
;---------------------------------------------------
    push esi
    push ecx
    mov eax, 0
   L1:
    add eax, [esi]
    add esi, 4
   LOOP L1
    pop esi
    pop ecx
ret
ArraySum ENDP
;---------------------------------------------------
DisplaySum PROC
;
; Отображает сумму элементов массива на экране
; Передаётся: EAX = сумма элементов
; Возвращается: ничего
; Вызывает: WriteString, WriteInt
;---------------------------------------------------
    push edx
    mov edx,offset promtoutptxt
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt
      ;  call CrLf

    pop edx
ret
DisplaySum ENDP
END main
```

хотел бы спросить, что делаю не так, может что-то не то с библиотекой Irvin-а, которую скачал с нета, может нужно как-то вызывать консоль?
ОС - Windows 32-разрядная
компилятор - masm32

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать что-нибудь попроще? В минимальном варианте:

```
.data
    decformat db "%d", 0
.code
; ...
    push 0DEADBEEFh
    push offset decformat
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Или так:

```
.model flat, c, STDCALL
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data
decformat   db  '%d',0

.code
Start:
    Invoke crt_printf, addr decformat, 1111
    ret
end Start
```

Comment: printf как включать?
extern не работате, пробовал, выводит, мол, символ не распознал
а библиотеку какую подключать?

Comment: См. обновление.